# Chai/Sinon: How to spy on the return value of a promise returned by a function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, integration-testing, sinon, chai

I'm setting up unit + integration tests for `onAfterDelete`:

```
Assessment.onAfterDelete = async () => {
  ...

  // Log assessment deleted
  await Activity.create({
    assessmentId,
    activityTypeId: ACTIVITY_TYPE.ASSESSMENT_DELETED,
  }, options);

  ...
};
```

While I know how to test that `Activity.create` was called, I'd really like to test that the `Activity` was successfully created.

If it wasn't asynchronous, then I'd use Sinon.spy as follows:

```
it('logs the assessment deleted activity', async () => {
  sinon.spy(Activity, 'create');
  await Assessment.onAfterDelete(...);
  expect(Activity.create).returned({
    activityTypeId: ACTIVITY_TYPE.ASSESSMENT_DELETED,
    assessmentId: standardAssessmentData.id,
  });
  Activity.create.restore();
});
```

Of course, this doesn't work as `Activity.create` returns a Promise.

After an hour Googling the various flavors of Chai and Sinon with promises, I'm yet to find a solution to this use case. How can I test this return value?

Comment: Shouldn't you be unit-testing `Activity.create()`?

Comment: @robertklep Yes and we will do, but I want to test the integration here to feel 100% confident that all fields provided are saving as expected (and catch issues if Activity.create changes in future)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`chai-as-promised`](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised):

```
const chai           = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

it('logs the assessment deleted activity', async () => {
  sinon.spy(Activity, 'create');
  await Assessment.onAfterDelete();

  // Make sure `Activity.create()` got called.
  expect(Activity.create.called).to.be.true;

  // Check the resolved value.
  await expect(Activity.create.firstCall.returnValue).to.eventually.equal({
    activityTypeId : ACTIVITY_TYPE.ASSESSMENT_DELETED,
    assessmentId   : standardAssessmentData.id,
  });

  // Restore the original.
  Activity.create.restore();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm using `chai-as-promised` but had expected the syntax to be more like `to.eventually.return`.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily spy on the the returned (resolved, rejected) **Promise** , with no 3rd party (using sinon only)

**Example:**

```
// Note: Activity.create returns a promise which we want to spy on its return/resolved promise

it('Should pass', async () => {

  // Spy on your function
  const mySpy = sinon.spy(Activity, 'create');

  // Invoke your function
  await Assessment.onAfterDelete(...);

  // Test resolved/rejected returned value (Note that we await on the returnValue)
  expect(await mySpy.firstCall.returnValue).to.deep.equal({...})

  // Restore function - remove spy
  mySpy.restore();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer to my question has been covered by robertklep, I've actually ended up wrapping the call to `Activity.create` in an internal method `Assessment.logDeleteActivity` and testing that.